# MySql Replace method with "/" in input string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure which takes input like

```
myProcedure("Fashion,Sports", "Shirts, Pants", null, null , "0,100")

myProc( productType, Item, ProductID, costprice, minMaxQuantity);
```

Now for the first parameter, `myProcedure` creates a mysql query somthing like

```
Select * from myTable where ProductType in ('Fashion,'Sports')
and Item in ('Shirts','Pants');
```

For creating "in" statement part I am using "Repalce" method of mysql

```
SET whrClause = REPLACE(productType, "," ," ',' ");
```

This way I am able to make a correct query, and even I am getting the desired results.

But the problem is, in input sometime I am getting

```
myProcedure("Adm/Husleie/Royalty,Fashion,Sports", "Shirts, Pants", null, null , "0,100");
```

now for first part of the first argument (i.e `Adm/Husleie/Royalty`)
Replace method is not working properly. I am not getting result for `ProductType = Adm/Husleie/Royalty` , but for Fashion and Sports I am getting the results.  Can someone help me. How can I use absolute string and I can use replace method as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

Change your replace statement to

```
SET whrClause =REPLACE(REPLACE(productType, "," ," ',' "),"/" ," ',' ");
```

Comment: Actually in database, we have productType with  "/" (Adm/Husleie/Royalty), So I cant replace that. I event tried using Adm\/Husleie\/Royalty in Replace method, but still it is not giving any result